# SQL Convert yyyy-mm-ddTHH:mm:ss to DateTime

Tags: sql, t-sql

How can I convert

```
2016-01-20T14:27:36.270239Z
```

To a SQL DateTime?

I have tried

```
CAST('2016-01-20T14:27:36.270239Z' AS datetime)
```

But receive a conversion error.

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(datetimeoffset,'2016-01-20T14:27:36.270239Z',127) AS DATETIME)
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that DATETIME is not precise enough to represent the value you are trying to store.

If you don't need to store the the value exactly as is, Kamran's answer may suit.

If you need the full precision, use a DATETIME2. e.g. :

```
SELECT CONVERT(Datetime2,'2016-01-20T14:27:36.270239Z',127)
```

Comment: Cheers for the response dude.